# Going into dual space for a vector product

Tags: tensor-products, quantum-mechanics

I am a bid confused regarding the notation for tensor products when going into dual-space

If $\left| \Psi \rangle \right. = \left| A \rangle \right. \left| B \rangle \right.$ is $ \left. \langle \Psi \right| = \left. \langle A \right| \left. \langle B \right|$ or $\left. \langle B  \right| \left. \langle A \right|$?

My guess is the last choice, since operators should act on

$\left| 0 \rangle \right. = \left( \begin{matrix}
  1 \\
  0
 \end{matrix} \right) $

$\left| 1 \rangle \right. = \left( \begin{matrix}
  0 \\
  1
 \end{matrix} \right) $

so

$\left| 01 \rangle \right. = \left| 0 \rangle \right. \left| 1 \rangle \right. = \left( \begin{matrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0
 \end{matrix} \right) $

But then, for me, it should be

$\left( \begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0
 \end{matrix} \right) = \left \langle 10 \right|$ But this is not correct if i calculate the tensor product, since

$\left \langle 1 \right| \left \langle 0 \right| = \left( \begin{matrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0
 \end{matrix} \right)$

For instance, shoulden't it be

$\left| 01 \rangle \right. \left \langle 10 \right| = \left( \begin{matrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 \end{matrix} \right) $ ?

I hope I have made my confusion clear

Comment: Hint: Tensor products, in general, don't commute.

Comment: It is interpreting the $<$ as opening an html tag. Enclose math in $\$$s. You should also use \langle and \rangle in the dollar signs.